# Run function on every 10th packet received in loop

Tags: javascript

Below is a function that runs a drawAccel() function on every packet received from the server. darwAccel() builds out a strip chart so constantly running it on every every packet received is slow enough in IE8 that it causes things to break. I would like to run it on every 10th (or variable number) packet received. What would be a good approach for this?

```
function messagecb(header, message) {
    if(header.type == 6) {
      // processEchoReply(message);

    } else if(header.type == 4) {
        var accels = message.b64UnpackAccelMsg();

    for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
        var accel = accels[index];
        var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

        addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);
    }

    drawAccel();

  } else if(header.type == 3) {
      // info
      var info2 = message.b64UnpackInfo2Msg();

      displayCurrentPosition(info2.fixtime, info2.lat, info2.lon, info2.alt);
      displayMobileStatus(info2.rssi, info2.bandClass, info2.batt);
  } else if(header.type == 11) {
      btReceive(header, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: why you can't try this ? setinterval http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is have a local variable that you check to see when it has a value of some multiple of 10.  Global variables will be a big problem and should be avoided like the plague.

```
function messagecb(header, message) {
    if(header.type == 6) {
      // processEchoReply(message);

    } else if(header.type == 4) {
        var accels = message.b64UnpackAccelMsg();

    for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
        var accel = accels[index];
        var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

        addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);
    }

    if ( typeof messagecb.counter == 'undefined' ) {
      messagecb.counter = 0;
    }

    ++messagecb.counter;
    if (messagecb.counter % 10 == 0) {
      drawAccel();
    }

  } else if(header.type == 3) {
      // info
      var info2 = message.b64UnpackInfo2Msg();

      displayCurrentPosition(info2.fixtime, info2.lat, info2.lon, info2.alt);
      displayMobileStatus(info2.rssi, info2.bandClass, info2.batt);
  } else if(header.type == 11) {
      btReceive(header, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: This method seems to be working great! Although I'm thinking I should implement a split in the code so that it doesn't check the counter if you are in a more modern browser. This way you still get a smooth animation in the chart if you are and a slower implementation in the lesser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a counter

```
var i=0;
function messagecb(header, message) {
    if(header.type == 6) {
      // processEchoReply(message);

    } else if(header.type == 4) {
        var accels = message.b64UnpackAccelMsg();

    for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
        var accel = accels[index];
        var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

        addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);
    }

    if(i%10 == 0 && i!=0) {drawAccel();} i++; 

  } else if(header.type == 3) {
      // info
      var info2 = message.b64UnpackInfo2Msg();

      displayCurrentPosition(info2.fixtime, info2.lat, info2.lon, info2.alt);
      displayMobileStatus(info2.rssi, info2.bandClass, info2.batt);
  } else if(header.type == 11) {
      btReceive(header, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't your i++ counter be outside the if statement?

Comment: Oops. thanks. initially thought of not using braces, and then messed it up.. :)

Comment: One thing, the global counter var i worries me, would this raise the chance for other problems due to overwrite? Of course defense to that could be using a more complex name too.

Comment: Yup  I would usa a different name  I believe in keeping it simple. Not over engineering it

Comment: Or pass it as an argument to the method  that way you can do away with global variable